# GDAL coordinate transformation not aligning with QGIS coordinate transformation

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a raster being changed from EPSG:27700 to EPSG:3857 coordinate reference system.

Within the QGIS application, I have found this coordinate transformation to fit the best

[image]

I've tried to replicate this coordinate transformation in GDAL and assumed that by declaring `-ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=helmert +x=371 +y=-111 +z=434 +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84"` as per the QGIS window, I'd get the same result. Sadly not. Using GDAL and this `-ct` my raster is ending up on the coast of Alaska when it should be in the UK.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the GDAL command I was using

```
gdalwarp -ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=helmert +x=371 +y=-111 +z=434 +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84" C:/new/DensA_20210506.tif C:/new/DensA_20210506_gdal.tif
```

Comment: Maybe you are changing the geotransformation but not the reference system. What happens if you include the `-t_srs EPSG:3857` parameter within the same gdalwarp command?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca adding ```-t_srs EPSG: 3857``` does the default geotransformation then, which isnt what I want as it is off by over 2m.

Comment: Did you try? Because i think you are overriding the default transformation with the `-ct` pipeline. Or open the raster layer in QGIS and just set EPSG:3857 as its CRS.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca yes I tried ```gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=helmert +x=371 +y=-111 +z=434 +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84" C:/new/DensA_20210506.tif C:/new/DensA_20210506_gdal_try.tif```

Comment: Your -ct pipeline doesn't seem like the one selected in the screenshot. Maybe you are copying the default one so obtaining it.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca you were right!!! My rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying a set of transformations and/or conversions through a PROJ pipeline inside the `-ct` parameter of *gdalwarp*, the coordinates of the pixels are changed, but not the reference system of those coordinates.

In order for the new coordinates to correspond to the same location on Earth as the previous ones, the target Spatial Reference System must also be modified through the `-t_srs` parameter.

The source geospatial location was already defined in the source file, through a geotransform matrix or control points, referenced to a source SRS. The set of operations from the source (in the file) to the destination (in the *-t_srs* parameter) SRS is overwritten with the *-ct* command, avoiding the search of the default operation within the PROJ database.

Therefore, to custom transform to a new SRS, it is necessary to define both `-ct` and `-t_srs` parameters on the *gdawarp* command line.